# able redirect to specify view controller after clicked remote notification but only VC but without navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, apple-push-notifications

i had setup an redirect after user click the push notification and it did worked. However the app is redirect to the View Controller without navigation bar and bottom toolbar.. Below are my redirect code : -

```
// Did receive notification method here...

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0)
{
    NSLog(@"user info1 is %@",userInfo);


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION_RECIEVED"
                                                            object:nil
                                                          userInfo:nil];

    UIStoryboard *mainsboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainsboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notice"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[This screenshot showing the notice storyboard properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Kjd.png)

[This screenshot showing the top navigation item properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGM3p.png)

Comment: First thing is you should use the `AnnouncementVC` as your `vc`'s class. Have you added a navigation bar manually? Or the navigation bar is being inherited from a previous controller?

Comment: the navigation is not inherited currently which showing "inherited (nothing)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question to mean that you expect the view controller to appear in the context of a navigation controller that you have configured in storyboard.  In that case, you'll need to do a little more to set things up:

1. find the navigation controller in your storyboard that contains the one with the "notice" ID, and give it a storyboard ID, too -- maybe something like "noticeNavigationController"
2. upon receiving the notification, build navigation controller from storyboard, too, and set it's root with the "notice" view controller that you know how to build...

   ```
   // as you have it
   UIStoryboard *mainsboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController *vc = [mainsboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notice"];

   // but now build a navigation controller, too
   UINavigationController *navVC = [mainsboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"noticeNavigationController"];
   // make your vc the root
   navVC.viewControllers = @[ vc ];

   // and present** that navigation controller
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

**Note, unless you're doing a presentation intentionally for some reason, it's more commonplace to just set the app's rootViewController to the navVC, rather than present it.

Comment: Right on the money. :)

Comment: cannot give it an storyboard ID regarding the navigation bar , the top bar don have any storyboard ID on id there , it showing Class : UINavigationItem

Comment: @aznelite89, be sure that the navigation controller is selected on the lefthand side, and select the identity inspector tab on the right.